# what happens to nsuserdefault data if the phone dies before synchronizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

Let's say i'm saving data about a user in NSUserDefaults and the user's phone dies before i can synchronize the data. What happens? Is all that data lost? Is it retained somehow?

Comment: In NSUserDefaults you shouldn't save lot of data and you should save it and synchronise instantly. It's very fast operation so you shouldn't really worry about losing user data. If you try to save lot of data you should consider save it somewhere else (file system, core data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a value for a key with `NSUserDefaults`, the data is first kept in memory. `NSUserDefaults` periodically writes the changes to disk (making them persistent) or you can call `synchronize`, if you can't wait (for instance if your app is about to quit).

If `synchronize` is not called (either automatically, or by you) before the app crashes or the phone dies, the new data is never written to disk and will be lost.

Comment: can you tell me how often it's automatically written, roughly? just for the sake of understanding

Comment: The documentation doesn't go into detail about that. It only states that changes are made persistent "periodically". But it would be easy to test that for yourself. Simply try changing a setting all the time and observe in what intervals the user defaults plist file is changed.

Comment: But anyway, you should usually call synchronize yourself. That's the safe way. If you edit a lot of settings in one go, you call synchronize once at the end. This way you avoid settings lost because of crashes (which of course are always bad, but at least you user should not lose his settings because of that).

Comment: Currently synchronize is called roughly 10 seconds after a 'set' call on iOS, and between 7 and 14 seconds on OSX